# ModSecurity 403 access denied

Tags: google-authentication, mod-security

I have this error in log when I try to access to a subdirectory:

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched phrase ".profile" at ARGS:scope. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec_vendor_configs/comodo_apache/09_Global_Other.conf"] [line "57"] [id "210580"] [rev "1"]
```

The request has .profile word in URI, but I use it in Google login scope.
Is it possibile, with .htaccess disable it ? I already tried use it:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

but it doesn't work.
I tried to put it on root .htaccess file and in subdirecory .htaccess file.

**UPDATE:**
The error in browser is:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /SUBDIR/index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <IfModule mod_security2.c>
     SecRuleUpdateTargetById 210580 !ARGS:'scope'
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry had a typo. Try without the dot before scope. Updated the answer.

Comment: Same result....I put it in ROOT .htaccess and subdir .htaccess file
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecRuleUpdateTargetById 210580 !ARGS:'scope'
</IfModule>

Comment: Mod_security.c only works with Apache 1. It’s almost certain you are using mod_security2.c. Answer updated again.

Comment: with new answer I got error 500 internal server error

Comment: Is it not working at all or are you still getting a 500 error? Try removing the If statements. It’s possible your ModSecurity does not allow htaccess overrides.

Comment: If I use IF statement with mod_security.c check I have 403 error. If i don't use any IF i got 500 error.

Comment: Mod_security.c or mod_security2.c? Do you have access to the server to see what version of ModSecurity is being used?

Comment: No i can't access to this level of configuration, but the IF without error is Mod_security.c, with Mod_security2.c I got 500 error

Comment: So mod_security.c doesn’t error but doesn’t do anything to disable the rule. Suggesting the If is basically ignored, suggesting that that module is not loaded (as I suspected). So let’s ignore that.

Comment: For mod_security2.c it’s weird that it errors with 500. Are you still getting that ModSecurity error or has it passed that one now and is it failing on a different one?

Comment: In log I have "SecRuleUpdateTargetById not allowed here"

Comment: Then it looks like your provider does not allow you to turn off ModSecurity rules in htaccess. You need to contact them to add the override for you.